# java OutputStreamWriter and CP437

Tags: java

I am trying the following code, my problem is with the characters i put to get the byte array

the char É should correspond to 144 according to its charset set but i got the value of -55 when i ran the code,

if i used $ i will get 36 which is correct?

thanks for your help

```
try {
   ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   Writer wr = new OutputStreamWriter(result, "CP437");
   wr.write("É");//
   wr.close();
   ba2 = result.toByteArray();
   result.close();

} catch (Exception x) {
   x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CP437 encoding requires 8 bits to store, I executed your code and found the value stored in a byte as -112, É corresponding to 144 is outside the range of a standard byte (-127 to 128). convert it to an unsigned or positive value to obtain the correct result, use the following code to convert to an unsigned value:

```
public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
    return b & 0xFF;
}
```

printing this value:

`System.out.println(unsignedToBytes((byte) ba2[0]));`

gives 144 which is your required value.